# Corda Accounts - Ability to move an account to a different host node

Tags: corda

In the Corda accounts library, in order to change the host "ownership" of the account from one node to another, one would need to change the `Host` in the AccountInfo state to the new host (node), along with share all vault states relevant to this account.

AccountInfo doesn't have an Update command ([AccountInfo commands](https://github.com/corda/accounts/blob/master/contracts/src/main/kotlin/com/r3/corda/lib/accounts/contracts/commands/AccountInfoCommands.kt)), meaning you cannot change the host once it is created.

- Has this feature been excluded for any reason?  Are there any plans to introduce an Update command (with supporting flows)?
- What steps would be involved in a move/transfer (host ownership)? And what are the potential caveats around this implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amol there will be work done on this in the future but as of now, there are two options which could help you resolve your issue.

1. Set up a new account on the new node. Generate new key(s) for the new account. Spend all the states from the old account to this new account.
2. If you control the all the keys used to participate in your states and can migrate them to the new node then you just need to import the key pairs somehow and then copy all the states across from the old node to the new node.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Sneha.
- Suggestion #1 is feasible. And will have to then do something at the application level to "blacklist" the account on the original host, inform about this to others, since the account cannot be "revoked" as well once created. So that is another feature request, if I may suggest :) 
- For suggestion #2, its not just a trivial task of copying states, right?  The state details might exist in multiple tables: transaction, vault, linearID table etc
Participants have to be updated as well. And exporting and moving private keys sounds like a bad idea in general

Comment: I will take your request to the product team :)